# jsView jQuery UI widget autocomplete Custom data and display

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsviews

I am initializing different jQuery UI autocomplete-widgets per jsviews-jqueryui-widgets API (https://www.jsviews.com/download/sample-tag-controls/jsviews-jqueryui-widgets.js), which is calling the jQuery UI autocomplete widget API.
This works fine!

But I want to modify the custom data and display of the autocomplete widget (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data).

I think, I need the implement a chaining method, but I don't know, how to implement it in the API of jsView.

**jsView Template:**

```
<script id="inputText" type="text/x-jsrender">
        <input type="text" data-link="{autocomplete value _source=~suggestionList}" />
</script>
```

**Chaining method:**

```
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<div>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</div>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

**Part of jsviews-jqueryui-widgets API**

```
autocomplete: {
  baseTag: "widget",
  widgetName: "autocomplete",
  linkedElement: "*",
  elem: "input",
  setSize: true,
  options: function() {
    var tag = this;
    return {
      change: function(evt, ui) {
        if (ui.item) {
          tag.updateValue(ui.item.value);
          // If there is a selected item, update bound value on keydown.
          // (Alternatively can set trigger=false to update on change)
        }
      },
      select: function(evt, ui) {
        if (ui.item) {
          tag.updateValue(ui.item.value);
        }
      },
      focus: function(evt, ui) {
        return false;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Please review and provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to create a derived `{^{myAutocomplete ...}}` tag, which overrides the _renderItem method, and the focus and select options:

```
$.views.tags("myAutocomplete", {
  baseTag: "autocomplete",
  onBind: function(tagCtx) {
    this.baseApply(arguments);
    var widget = this.widget;
    widget._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<div>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</div>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
    widget.options.focus = function( event, ui ) {
      this.value = ui.item.label;
      // Other rendering code?
      return false;
    };
    widget.options.select = function( event, ui ) {
      this.value = ui.item.label;
      // Other rendering code, such as:
      // $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
      return false;
    };
  }
});
```

You could choose to override just the _renderItem method, and optionally override the options on the the individual instances:

```
$.views.tags("myAutocomplete", {
  baseTag: "autocomplete",
  onBind: function(tagCtx) {
    this.baseApply(arguments);
    var widget = this.widget;
    widget._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<div>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</div>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
  }
});
```

then:

```
<input type="text"
 data-link="{myAutocomplete value _source=~suggestionList _focus=~focus _select=~select}" />
```

or

```
{^{myAutocomplete value _source=~suggestionList _focus=~focus _select=~select /}}
```

See the JsViews documentation topic: *[Accessing widget options, events and methods](https://jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/jqui/api)*.